# Set created and modified on a listitem through Sharepoint Client Object model

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I am copying data from one site to another throught the Sharepoint Client Object model. This works for the most fields. The Created and Modified will not change correctly though.

The code is like this:

```
targetItem.Update();
targetList.Context.ExecuteQuery();
targetItem.FieldValues["Created"] = sourceItem["Created"];
targetItem.Update();
targetList.Context.ExecuteQuery();
```

I have set the date before, but through debugging I found that the dates were set on the ExecuteQuery so I thought it might be possible to change afterwards.. But no luck..

Is it possible to set an attribute that passes .SystemUpdate or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to set the ReadOnly flag to false [SPField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfield.readonlyfield%28v=office.14%29.aspx)